# TypeScript 2.0 control flow analysis and never type

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have this function in TypeScript 2.0:

```
function test(a:string) {
    var b = typeof a === "function" ? [a] : a;
}
```

**Expected** behavior:
Type of `b` is `string`. A warning could be issued for a condition that is *always* false.

**Actual** behavior: 
Type of `b` is `never[] | string`.

Why is that?

Comment: I don't know if there's a very interesting answer here except that `tsc` is smart, but not *that* smart.

Comment: Seems that the compiler is smart enough. Returning a `never` means exactly what you expected. The only thing that isn't very clear is why it returns `never[]` and not `never`, but even that can be rationalized as you expect to get an array if that condition is true, but as it's never the case you still get an array back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just played with this and, thinking about it, actually the TS compiler is pretty smart. TSC is well-aware of the typeof operator and tracks it in flow type analysis.

One of the really cool things about TS is that, rather than imposing a high-brow, high-priest, OO-like (think multi-multi-level class hierarchies), contravariant and covariant types (think Scala `[+T]`, `[-T]` clever but complex) upon you, TSC simply tries to model JS types according to the beautiful mess that they are, and it does this with the simplest machinery possible.

TS's type system is a goldilocks type system in a way: not too much and not too little; just right.

So, going with that prolog, let's analyse what's happening in answer to your question "Why is that?".

The type of the ternary expression `condition ? X : Y` is the union of `typeof(X)` and `typeof(Y)`. This is because, in the general case, X gets returned when the condition is true & its type is `typeof(X)` and Y gets returned otherwise & its type is `typeof(Y)`, so it has to be one or the other. Every JS programmer carries this type flow analysis in her/his head because vanilla JS doesn't have any formal syntax for writing types down.  But TypeScript, FaceBook's Flow & other compile-to-JS systems bring type syntax to the JS table and so now we can recognise the type of the ternary construct as being `typeof(X) | typeof(Y)`.

In your example, X is [a] and Y is string so what the type that the compiler is trying to figure out is typeof([a]) | typeof(a). The RHS is easy: it's just `string` because the function's argument said so. The LHS type has to be an array type because `[a]` says so and therefore it's going to be written out in TS type syntax as X[]. If just we can figure out what X is.

For the LHS, the compiler firstly deduces that `typeof(a)` has to be Function because the condition says so. But the function's signature says that `typeof(a)` is `string`.  Therefore, in the context of `[a]`, `typeof(a)` must simultaneously be `Function` as well as `string`.  This sounds kinda quantum (think quantum states) but it's not really blinding science. It is a simple conjunction or intersection of types (big words for the typewise AND operator) and this can be written as (Function & string). So now the overall type of that ternary expression is `(Function & string)[] | string`.

Lastly, the compiler knows that the intersection of the set of all Function values and the set of all string values is the empty set. Thus TSC further reduces `Function & string` to `never` since that value can "never happen" which is why, in this very long-winded answer, TSC says that the type is `never[] | string`.

However, it is also true that an array of nevers can never happen so that's another empty set of values. This brings us to your expected behavior that the type of b is just `string` which is a trivial subset (as in identical set) to `never[] | string`.  The compiler could have calculated this extra step and reduced the type expression further. That's either a feature or a bug depending on whether you think simplicity is a feature or otherwise!

Inline with Nitzan's answer, `never[]` can never happen as much as never can never happen so these types represent the same set of values. `never[]` is probably a little more precise because it tells you the shape (it's a container) of what might have been returned if indeed anything were to be returned.

On the other hand, your function does not ever throw an exception so to say that the type could be reduced to `never | string` as Nitzan suggests is probably wrong or misleading. `never | string` is the type you will get for the ternary expression:

`condition ? throw Error("WTF") : "Ecma Scriptus MMXV"`

I love these little puzzles and have often wondered if an empty basket of apples is the same as an empty basket of oranges.

Cheers.